# third party cookies not written on IE with iframe, even with P3P

Tags: php, iframe, cookies, shopping-cart, p3p

I designed the framing site: pishonworld.com, which frames wholesalecentral.com/pishonworld/store.cfm.

When customers use IE to shop on my site, their shopping cart gets cleared out as soon as they leave the cart. I have some really good things about P3P, so I added P3P to my index.php, but cart is still cleared out on IE.

Does this P3P need to go to the framing page? or the framed page?

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this to work?

Thank you in advance for your help!

The following is my index.php.

---

```
<?php
    header('p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Pishon World</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mailWrapper">
  <div id="pageContent">

  <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>

<table width="1100" border="0">
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td><iframe align="middle" name="iframe" id="iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="1100" height="650" src="welcome.php" seamless="seamless">Your browser is too old and it does not support pishonworld.com.
    <br />
    Please visit us at http://www.wholesalecentral.com/pishonworld/store.cfm  to place your order.</iframe></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>

<?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The P3P header should go to the page which will be loaded into a frame. It seems that you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
P3P: CP=”ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL”
```

See http://www.marco.org/2007/04/27/p3p-sucks-how-to-get-frame-cookies-unblocked-in-ie6
I have used

```
ALL ADM DEV PSAo COM OUR OTRo IND ONL
```

in the past and it works!

Also I would add this header to all your pages that are part of this process.